# Converting multiple lines of mysql string into predefined csv format?

Tags: mysql, database, excel, csv, converters

this is more like a how-to question about csv, excel, mysql files than a standard coding question. However I really would appreciat some help with this.

**I have this predefined CSV format, that I need in order to import it to a database with Sequel Pro.**

```
ID,"user_login","user_pass","user_nicename","user_email","user_url","user_registered","user_activation_key",user_status,"display_name"

1,"some_name","$P$BDMmGci3KAqNQwfPtgzfQTp8D3k7bC.","some_name","some.name@gmx.net","","2013-06-27 11:32:08","",0,"Some Name"
```

---

**On the other hand I have an old database file looking like this …**

```
CREATE TABLE `ezxsubscription` (                                
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,                         
  `version_status` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                            
  `subscriptionlist_id` int(11) default '0',                            
  `email` varchar(255) default '',                              
  `hash` varchar(255) default '',                               
  `status` int(11) default '0',                             
  `vip` int(11) default '0',                                
  `last_active` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                           
  `output_format` varchar(255) default '',                          
  `creator_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                            
  `created` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                           
  `confirmed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                         
  `approved` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                          
  `removed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',                           
  `user_id` int(11) default '0',                                
  `bounce_count` int(11) default '0',                               
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`,`version_status`)                          
) TYPE=MyISAM;                                  

--                                  
-- Dumping data for table `ezxsubscription`                         
--                                  

INSERT INTO `ezxsubscription` VALUES (454,1,5,'name@surname.com','31b6bde64e1282ba82d7d0c8ad6ebaa9',2,0,0,'2',1127,1142840848,0,1142840868,0,2633,0);   
INSERT INTO `ezxsubscription` VALUES (1,1,5,'name.name@gmail.com','fff4b8d75ecdfad43ed8c89444939cfb',2,0,0,'2',10,1141956489,1141956489,1141956489,0,14,0);
…
```

The database has like 400 users in it that I couldn't sort by hand. I need to have the database file to be in the format of the predefined CSV above. Where the email-address should be the `user_login` and `user_name`. The rest of the old database like `approved`, `removed` or whatever can simply be disregarded. **It's just about the user-login and the passwords.**

Any clever idea on how to do so? The aim is to import all the old users of the old database to the new database (based on Wordpress).

I would really appreciate some tips or tricks.

Thank you in advance.
Matt

---

Update:

**This is the old format of the `ezxsubscription` table.**

```
"id","version_status","subscriptionlist_id","email","hash","status","vip","last_active","output_format","creator_id","created","confirmed","approved","removed","user_id","bounce_count"
1,1,5,"andreas@gmail.at","fff4b8d75ecdfad43ed8c89444939cfb",2,0,0,2,10,1141956489,1141956489,1141956489,0,14,0
```

**All I wanna do now is convert this users to the new wordpress format:**

```
"ID","user_login","user_pass","user_nicename","user_email","user_url","user_registered","user_activation_key","user_status","display_name"
1,"local","$P$BCf7QHr3rsp0YNZd7eMfYgncRZmR6j0","local","temp@local.dev","","2013-03-14 18:46:29","",0,"local"
```

I do even have problems understanding what the `hash` in the old db means.
All I wanna do is copy all existing old users to the new wordpress database so that I have the e-mail addresses and the passwords, so that they are able to login again.

So I want to make the old email the username of the new wordpress db. And the `hash` should probably be the new `user_pass` in wordpress. However I only hope that the `hash` is the password of the current login — I don't even know for sure.

Kind Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html) syntax to create a CSV file from your old table with a query like this

```
SELECT *
  INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/your/file.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM
(
  SELECT 'id', 'user_login', 'user_pass', 'user_nicename','user_email','user_url','user_registered','user_activation_key','user_status','display_name'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, email, hash, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1), email, '', created, '', status, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1)
    FROM ezxsubscription
) q
```

Content of the created file:

```
"id","user_login","user_pass","user_nicename","user_email","user_url","user_registered","user_activation_key","user_status","display_name"
"454","name@surname.com","31b6bde64e1282ba82d7d0c8ad6ebaa9","name","name@surname.com","","1142840848","","2","name"
"1","name.name@gmail.com","fff4b8d75ecdfad43ed8c89444939cfb","name.name","name.name@gmail.com","","1141956489","","2","name.name"
```

Comment: @matt Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Hey @peterm. Thank you for your quick answer. Since I'm fairly new to this I have some more (probably dumb) questions. 1.) In order to run your script, I do have to setup the already existing users as a table, right? Right now I have a .sql file with the code I posted in my question above (just with 400lines more of users). 2.) I have SequelPro on my Mac installed and I'm able to connect to my local Wordpress Database where I want the old users of the old .sql file to be imported to.

Comment: @matt You're welcome. 1) Yes in order for it to work you have to create that table from the script. You can do it in any database accessible to you. 2) Now your second raises important question why do you need a csv file at all then? You can create a table with old data in you WP db and then just use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT...` to migrate data directly to your new table

Comment: You're right. I managed to create the table `ezxsubscription` within my wordpress database … http://cl.ly/RM1H … would you mind helping me out with the right syntax to copy the users to the wp_users table?
This data http://cl.ly/RM2w to this -> http://cl.ly/RM0L

Comment: Btw. there are already 6 users with ID 1-6 reserverd. So the old user ids should start with 7 I guess.

Comment: @matt Yes I can help you with that. But you need to post new table schema in a textual form as a `CREATE TABLE` statement to see actual data types. It's impossible to work with pictures. You also need to explain better which columns from the old table should go to which columns in the new one (I mean not obvious ones like `user_registered`, `user_activation_key`...).